# Running sed command from python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a buffer from an input file and write it to an output file and is not working.
here is my snippet.

```
nums = 54466
nume = 78954
input_file=open(sys.argv[1],"r");
out_file = open(outp, "w")
subprocess.call(['sed', '-n', ''nums,numep'', input_file], stdout=out_file)
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is `''nums,numep''` supposed to be? Are you trying to quote something with two single quotes?

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: Why the hell would you want to run `sed` from python?

Answer (score 0):

Likely  you are trying to call

```
sed -n '$LINE1,$LINE2p' input_file
```

To print the lines between $LINE1 and $LINE2.

Python string substitution works in a different way - try replacing

```
''nums,numep''
```

with

```
"'%s,%sp'" % (nums, nume)
```

or

```
"'{},{}p'".format(nums, nume)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're better off implementing the logic **within** python, and not calling `sed`, however, something like this would work:

```
import subprocess
#set output_file and input_file
nums = 54466
nume = 78954
cmd = "sed -n '{s},{e}p' {i} > {o}".format(i=input_file,o=output_file,s=nums,e=nume)
subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just demonstrating why you should not run `sed`…

```
from itertools import islice

nums, nume = 54466, 78954
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as infile, open(outp, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in islice(infile, nums, nums + nume):
        outfile.write(line)
```

This is simpler, less error-prone and more portable that invoking an external program.

Comment: Python 2's with statement [accepts multiple comma separated with items](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) just fine.

Comment: Right, I went from 2.6 to 3 directly so I did not follow all updates. I'm removing the warning then, thanks for commenting.